# How to call Oracle function returning Table of record

Tags: java, spring, jdbctemplate, spring-jdbc

I have to get data from a function which returns a table of record. For example

Package is pkg1

Record defined inside package is:

```
type rec is record(id number,name varchar2(40));
```

Table of Record defined inside package is:

```
type rec_tbl is table of rec;
```

Function defined inside package is :

```
FUNCTION get_rec_tbl() RETURN rec_tbl;
```

Now What I need to do is: Using spring jdbc or spring jdbctemplate get values from function and process it. I am not sure how to do this.

Can some one help?

Answer (score 2):

[RECORD](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/java.111/b31224/apxref.htm#g1009796) type is not directly supported by Oracle JDBC drivers.

There is an [ugly workaround](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/java.111/b31224/apxref.htm#BABFECBJ), as an official JDBC reference states. Never used it myselft, thought.

Answer (score 2):

As a workaround you can just run such select query:

```
select * from table(get_rec_tbl())
```